# why does setState contain another function here, rather than a simple property update?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

On this page: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

This bit of code has me confused:

```
  this.setState(() => ({
    redirectToReferrer: true
  }))
```

Why not simply do:

```
  this.setState({
    redirectToReferrer: true
  })
```

??

Comment: In this case I’m not sure. Generally, you might use a function in setState to make sure you have access to the most current state/props (e.g., (prevState, prevProps) => ...)). But when you’re not actually using the values passed to the function, not sure why you’d use it.

Comment: @Nick thanks for the comment. I can confirm that both seem to be working, so the first may not be necessary.